# Windows mobile device center wont connect if I am connected with RDP

Tags: windows-8, windows-mobile

I have a separete developer computer for a windows CE device, and are using "Windows mobile device center" to uppload files to the device.
When logged in as usual on that computer the device connects just fine, but when I connect to the computer with RDP, the device wont connect.

If I log in on the computer, put the device in the dock, it will connect and will be connected if I logging in with RDP as long as I dont close the program.

So the question, what is blocking the connection for the device when logged in with RDP?